# Referencing buttons on msgbox

Tags: windows, vb.net

I am coding a message box into my game to confirm a process is completed. My message box is displayed, and functioning. How can I make it where when I click OK it runs a new part of my code? (I do not know how to connect code to the buttons within a message box)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyxbC.png)

Comment: A `MessageBox` will return a `DialogResult`. You can check that result to know which button was clicked. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.messagebox?view=windowsdesktop-6.0

Comment: Also FWIW using `MsgBox` is from `vb6` days, I would use `MessageBox`. Even though `MsgBox` delegates to `MessageBox`, I would still recommend going directly with `MessageBox`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
   Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        ProgressBar1.Value += 1
        If ProgressBar1.Value = 1000 Then
            Timer1.Enabled = False
            Dim msgResult As MsgBoxResult = MsgBox("Program has been loaded", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Click to continue")

            If msgResult = MsgBoxResult.Ok Then
                DoSomething()
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub DoSomething()
        MsgBox("You did something")
    End Sub
```

Alternatively, you could just call one of your subs after your MsgBox without getting the result since there is only one result that would be returned anyway.

```
   Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        ProgressBar1.Value += 1
        If ProgressBar1.Value = 1000 Then
            Timer1.Enabled = False
           MsgBox("Program has been loaded", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Click to continue")
           DoSomething()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub DoSomething()
        MsgBox("You did something")
    End Sub
```

Comment: Is there any way I can improve my answer so that it might be upvoted?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter. Most likely they don't like that you used `MsgBox`, which is supposed to be just for backwards compatibility, instead of the newer [MessageBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.messagebox?view=windowsdesktop-6.0).

Comment: I used it because that is what OP had in their code. Perhaps I should have suggested MessageBox.

Comment: your answer actually really helped, and I didn't know messagebox existed, so I'll have to try it out!